# Passing selected file name from tkinter to a different function in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've written a python script which basically reads all PDF files from a folder and opens them one by one.

filename.py

```
def final():
    try:
        filepath = [file for file in glob.glob("PDF_files/*.pdf")]
        my_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for file in filepath:
            doc = fitz.open(file)
            # rest of the code
```

And I have written a script wherein using tkinter, I'm selecting a file and then executing `final()`

using_tkinter.py

```
import tkinter, tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from filename import final
root = tkinter.Tk()


def main():
    files = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files')
    msgbox = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Add files', 'add extra files', icon='warning')
    final()
    return list(files), msgbox, final


files, msgbox, final = main()

all_files = files

while msgbox == 'yes':
    files_2, msgbox, final = main()
    for i in files_2:
        files.append(i)

root.destroy()
```

My problem here is that the script `using_tkinter.py` runs fine but the files that I am selecting through it are not getting selected in filename.py file's `final()` function.

So for eg: if in PDF_files folder there are a total of 10 pdf files `final()` will read all of them.

but when I select 3 or 1 PDF file from any folder/PDF_files folder then also it reads all 10.

What change do I have to make if I have to run the `final()` as per user selects the file?
How do I pass the selected file name from tkinter to a different function in python?
Please help!

Comment: Simply pass `files` as an argument of `final()`.

Comment: @acw1668 where exactly do I need to pass it? in using_tkinter.py or  in filename.py?

Comment: solved it! thanks @acw1668